Возможно ли опубликовать новое приложение в AppStore под старым приложением, при том, что это разные проекты с разными bundle identifier
Есть приложение уже опубликованное. У него свой bundle identifier, это другой проект, но с теми же целями. И есть новое приложение, новая сборка со своим bundle identifier. Оба приложения это магазины. 1 старая версия, 2 новая версия. Возможно ли заменить в сторе 1 на 2?
В документации толком ничего не нашел.

Нельзя.
Можно просто поменять у нового приложения bundle id на старый – тогда для пользователей приложение просто обновится с версии 1 на версию 2. Листинг в сторе останется старым, однако при желании можно обновить все метаданные и сбросить рейтинг и отзывы. Ещё плюс – пользователи обновятся автоматически и им не нужно рассказывать про новое приложение. Минус – всякие user defaults, документы и keychain старого приложения не сбросятся, их нужно чистить.
Либо есть альтернатива – выложить новое приложение, и старое удалить из стора. Минус – у пользователей их может в теории остаться оба, удалить старое с телефонов могут только они сами.
